# Should "I am going to do sth" be repeated?

Tags: verbs

I am puzzled. Which is the correct variant?

> 1. "I am going to do my homework, and I am going to play a game of chess with my neighbour."
> 2. "I am going to do my homework and play a game of chess with my neighbour".

Maybe, in the first sentence, we mean a sequence of actions, and in the second sentence we mean that the person is going to do his homework and play chess simultaneously? Sorry, I tried to find the answer but I failed.

Comment: You could stick "then" in there i.e. "and then..".

Comment: Cascabel, thank you. Sorry, one more question. Does it mean that "I am going to do my homework and play a game of chess", is incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect"? Are you concerned more with sequence of events, or grammar? They are all fine grammatically, but possibly ambiguous...

Comment: Cascabel, I see now. Thank you very much.

Comment: They are both fine and mean the same thing. If you want to be clear that these are sequential and not simultaneous, add *then*, as @Cascabel suggested.

Comment: Tinfoil Hat, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Contrast '[I am going to do] [tonight's homework] and [Thursday's too].' with '[I am going to] [do tonight's homework] and [watch Batwoman on TV].' The deletions  are different. As Cascabel implies, adding 'then', padding, makes the second type of sentence sound more natural.